# <f:setPropertyActionListener> not invoked when using with <p:confirm>

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.3 and I got a issue when trying to use **f:setPropertyActionListener** with **p:confirm** in a p:commandButton.

The dialog is shown but the setter method defined in f:setPropertyActionListener **is not invoked** when it is used with p:confirm. So my bean attribute called *produtoSelecionado* is not set properly.

My XHTML code:

```
    <h:form id="produtosForm">
        ...
        <p:dataTable ...>
            ...
                <p:commandButton
                    icon="ui-icon-trash"
                    title="Excluir"
                    process="@this :dialogExclusao"
                    update=":dialogExclusao :produtosForm:produtosTable"
                    oncomplete="PF('dialogExclusao').show()">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                        value="#{produto}"
                        target="#{pesquisaProdutosBean.produtoSelecionado}" />
                    <p:confirm
                        header="Exclusão de produto"
                        message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir o produto #{pesquisaProdutosBean.produtoSelecionado.sku}?"
                        icon="ui-icon-trash" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>

    <component:dialog-exclusao
        id="dialogExclusao"
        updateComponents=":produtosForm:produtosTable"
        yesAction="#{pesquisaProdutosBean.excluir}" />
```

The custom component defined above called *dialog-exlusao* is a global generic p:confirmDialog, that is used in multiple pages in the project:

```
<composite:interface>
<composite:attribute
    name="yesAction"
    method-signature="void yesAction()" />
<composite:attribute name="updateComponents" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <p:confirmDialog
        id="dialogConfirmacaoExclusao"
        global="true"
        widgetVar="dialogConfirmacaoExclusao">

    <p:button
        value="Não"
        styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
        onclick="PF('dialogConfirmacaoExclusao').hide(); return false;" />
    <p:commandButton
        value="Sim"
        oncomplete="PF('dialogConfirmacaoExclusao').hide()"
        styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"
        process="@this"
        update="dialogConfirmacaoExclusao #{cc.attrs.updateComponents}"
        action="#{cc.attrs.yesAction}" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Below my bean attribute with its getter and setter:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PesquisaProdutosBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Produto produtoSelecionado;
```

...

```
public Produto getProdutoSelecionado() {
    return produtoSelecionado;
}

public void setProdutoSelecionado(Produto produtoSelecionado) {
    this.produtoSelecionado = produtoSelecionado;
}

}
```

When I remove p:confirm tag, f:setPropertyActionListener is triggered correctly!

Is it a PF bug? How can I show the dialog in my custom component and set the bean attribute at same time, in the click of commandButton?

tks!

Comment: Will it be triggered *after* confirming?

Comment: No, it's never triggered! It's completelly ignored!